# Request is not available in this context -> In Global.asax -> what is replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, global-asax

why the below line has error in global.asax :

```
string RelativeFilePath = "~/" + (AbsoluteFilePath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty)).Replace("\\", "/");
```

Error :

> Request is not available in this context

what is the replacement?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hosting your application in IIS7 integrated pipeline HttpContext objects are not available in `Application_Start`. For your scenario you could do this instead:

```
string relativeFilePath = "~/" + AbsoluteFilePath
    .Replace(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, String.Empty)
    .Replace("\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

In IIS7 or greater, the Integrated pipeline was introduced, and some rules changed. You cannot access the current HttpContext in Application_Start. [Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/reganschroder/archive/2008/07/25/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-application-start.aspx) more information.

To quote, here's your options:

> **So, what does this mean to you?**
>
> Basically, if you happen to be accessing the request context in
>   Application_Start, you have two choices:
>
> Change your application code to not use the request context
>   (recommended). 
>   Move the application to Classic mode (NOT recommended).

Since you're just getting the application's physical path, I'd stick with Integrated Mode and just change your code.