# Request is not available in this context Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-2.0

On a shared hosting where I uploaded my Application files, I get the aforementioned exception each time I log on to the website. Below is the exception with it's stack trace.

---

> Request is not available in this context
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available
>   in this context
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +8891008
>   Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebConfigModuleInfoStore.GetConfiguration(String
>   configFilePath) +115
>   Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebConfigModuleInfoStore.PopulateSection(ModulesConfigurationSection
>   section, String rootDirectory) +186
>   Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebConfigModuleInfoStore.GetModuleConfigurationSection()
>   +79    Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebModuleEnumerator.EnumerateModules()
>   +173    Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication.LoadModules()
>   +216    Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication.Application_Start(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +149
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +2761334
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +128
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +188
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +295
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetPipelineApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +56
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +231
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8994307 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +333

I can see it's from `Application_Start` event from Global.asax. But I don't see what may be causing the exception. Below is the code in the event;

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"\Config\tasks.config"));
        XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("Tasks/Task");

        this._scheduler = new TaskScheduler(nodes);
        this._scheduler.StartTasks();
    }
```

What could I be possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757524/request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-global-asax-what-is-replace and http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik Thanks for your response. But if you notice my code posted in the question, I used `HostingEnvironment` class instead of `Server` that uses httpRequest as the asnwers in the links suggested. Still, it isn't working.

Comment: Check for the Permission of the `Hosting Enviroment` path Folder

Comment: @Webruster There's no provision on the plesk panel to set permissions.

Comment: @Webruster I found it. The folder is set to full control but it still gives the error.